# Liquibase default role when creating objects in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, roles

In my application Liquibase uses a special user, `liquibase` in order to connect to the database and apply all the change sets. As a result all created tables, sequences, function etc have user `liquibase` as owner. The `liquibase` user is member of the role `db_ddl_admin` and I would like this role to become the owner of all created objects. I could achieve this by adding the statement `SET ROLE TO db_ddl_admin` at the beginning of each change set, but I don't like this approach. Is there a centralized way to set such setting in Liquibase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Liquibase uses a single connection for all changesets. So it's enough to run the `SET ROLE` statement once at the start of the changeLog:

```
<databaseChangeLog ...>

    <changeSet runAlways="true" author="setup" id="init-role" dbms="postgresql">
      <sql>SET ROLE TO db_ddl_admin</sql>
    </changeSet>

    ... your changeSets go here ...

</databaseChangeLog>
```